# html5 video buffer not effect in Chrome 50

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, video

[image: file request]

video preload mode is 'auto'

look at these three requests, first when I enter this page, video start get metadata(18.1MB)

the second request is when I start video and pause, browser start get buffer and totally buffered(304M)

but when I start and pause again, or seek to any video time, browser start request video file again! the last request. Especially when I set network offline, I can't get stream that I have totally loaded, Unbelievable!

Why chrome behaviour like this?

Comment: In the Chrome DevTools hit "F1" to bring up the settings. do you have "*Disable Cache (While DevTools is open)*" checked off? That may have something to do with it...

Comment: @rgthree thanks, a stupid mistake...the same setting in Firefox but cached so I ignore this..